# Что делать, если конкурент создал дубль сайта?

Tags: seo, раскрутка

С 4 по 9 июля позиции сайта провалились в Яндексе на 13 позиций. Просматривая веб-мастер, обнаружил появление 6 внешних ссылок с 1 по 3 июля. Перейдя по ним, увидел полную копию своего сайта, от фавикона до указания расположения sitemap сайта. Правда, у них система не битрикс, а какая-то неизвестная. В службу поддержки Яндекса об обнаружении описанного уже написал. Что еще можно сделать?

Comment: У вас есть патент на сайт? Может быть это вы скопировали сайт один в один, правда на битриксе :)

Comment: @iKey посмотрите в правый нижний угол этого сайта, что там написано.